# Was lying morally wrong in Medieval Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, morals

It is my understanding that in medieval Europe, practical jokes were popular, tales from distant lands were often greatly exaggerated, and deception was common in the market place (baking stones in bread, covering rotten grain with fresh grain to hide it, making pots out of soft metal and coating them with harder metal... the list goes on).

These behaviors, if seen today, are/would be seen as morally wrong.

Was lying and deception considered as morally wrong in the middle ages as it is now, or was it more acceptable?

Comment: It's my understanding that, *today*, practical jokes are popular, tales from distant lands (and distant times) are exaggerated, and that deception is common in the market place - especially the online marketplace. Prevalence of falsehood doesn't necessarily equate with diminished ethical standards: people know these things are wrong, but still do them. Do you have a source for their being more widespread in former times than they are today?

Comment: Common story telling often doesn't take truth as a primary necessary virtue - then and now. Exaggerations etc. to make a story more exciting are fairly normal. We even created whole industries that deal with just that (movies, literature). For entertainment it was fairly common. If it was done for personal gain then it was just as frowned upon as today. If you're a poor sob, you're going to be hanged, if you're powerful, you got out of it pretty easy most of the time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for this question to be closed as off-topic. The question fits both its [tag:middle-ages] and [tag:morals] tags. History is often classified as part of the social sciences. Cultural practices are an important part of historical study. And there is no better Stack Exchange site to ask this question.

Comment: If you're invested in the question, there's an in-depth book on the history of lying in western Europe going up to Enlightenment (I just happened to remember it from my to-read list): The Devil Wins
A History of Lying from the Garden of Eden to the Enlightenment. Try skimming the reviews for the broad thesis.

Answer (score 8):

Re "deception was common in the market place" - both the cities and the guilds fiercely controlled the quality of merchandise offered.

Since you mentioned bread, punishments for cheating about the weight of bread included [having literally to wade through shit in front of the public, or being locked into a cage and being dunked into water while being mocked by the assembled crowd](http://www.museum-brotkultur.de/pdf/13Verordnungen%20und%20Strafen.pdf).

This does not sound like cheating was considered acceptable.

The TV documentation (German) "[Ein Tag im Mittelalter](https://www.zdf.de/dokumentation/terra-x/ein-tag-im-mittelalter-102.html)" (a day in the middle ages) explains a bit about guild regulations (starting at 34.55). Punishment for  the violation of guild rules (which includes deviating from the quality standards set by the "Zünfte", the guilds) is explicitly referred to as "Ehrenstrafen", i.e. "dishonoring punishment". So apart from tangible consequences (which might very well exclude being barred from your profession and/or exile) public humiliation was intended to be a huge part of your punishment. This might indicate that violations were not that rare, but it certainly means they were not considered acceptable.